# Webpack build is working fine however watch is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using command

> webpack serve --hot --watch --progress OR webpack serve --hot --progress

to start a server.

> Webpack Config file

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: ["**/node_modules"],
  },
  entry: "./source/js/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/js"),
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].min.js",
    publicPath: "/assets/",
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "assets"),
    compress: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

[image: Console]

This is the console output I am getting but webpack is not watching for changes. Although it was watching for changes a few days back.
P.S : I am new to webpack.

Comment: have you tried setting `mode` to `development`?

Comment: yes i have tried it ... still not working

Comment: what files did you change and which folders are they residing in?

Comment: i change absolutely nothing. i think something might have been changed when i did npm install

Comment: i meant which files did you update that you had expected webpack to watch and reload